# Inequality with two variables and a conditional equation

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Can someone help me solve this inequality?

Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers with $(x + 1) (y + 2) = 8$.
Prove:
$$(xy - 10)^2 \geq 64$$
Furthermore, determine all pairs $(x,y)$ of real numbers for which equality holds.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! Please post what you've tried so far and where you got stuck. That way more people will be eager to take a look at your post and they'll better know how to offer help.

Comment: @Tanny Sieben Since $8^2=64$ I have tried substituting the $64$ for $(x+1)^2(y+2)^2$. Then I took the squareroot on both sides and now I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick algebraic proof: Note that clearly $y \neq -2$ (otherwise the product would be 0). Thus we get $x = \frac{8}{y+2} - 1 = \frac{6-y}{y+2}$.
Now we have $xy = \frac{y(6-y)}{y+2}$ and some quick sketching and checking extrema points should give the inequality. However we can plug in and prove it directly: the condition to prove becomes

$$(xy-10)^2 \geq 8^2 \iff (xy-18)(xy-2) \geq 0 \iff \left( \frac{y(6-y)}{y+2} - 18\right)\left(\frac{y(6-y)}{y+2} - 2\right) \geq 0$$

The expression can be rewritten as
$$\frac{1}{(y+2)^2}(-y^2 + 6y - 18y - 36)(-y^2 +6y - 2y - 4) \geq 0$$
and now this immediately becomes

$$\frac{1}{(y+2)^2}(y+6)^2(y-2)^2 \geq 0,$$

which is clearly true. $\square$

We have equality when $y=-6$ or $2$, so $(x,y) = (-3,-6)$ or $(1,2)$.

Comment: Thank you very very v.....y much.